# Adding php code to html anchor tag

Tags: php, anchor

I'm trying to access an uploaded image which i've saved on my server (in the uploads folder) using the anchor tag. The aim is the provide like a zoom feature. The zoom works fine but the image doesn't display.
i tried something like this

```
<?php 
 //$txt is the actual image name and $image is the name saved in uploads folder,$ext is the extension like .jpg or so.
 $image = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext; 
?>
```

in the HTML

```
//image isn't displayed using
<a href = "<?php echo "uploads/$image" ?>"></a>
```

but displays if i use

```
<a href = "uploads/image.jpg"></a>.
```

is there a way i can access the images with php code in the  tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon and the $variable is enclosed in single quotes and is therefore not expanded.

```
<a href="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>">Image</a>
```

Anthony.

Comment: hi, i have one more question. I have some html code in my script which i'm executing through echo. Suppose i want to access an image in the uploads folder from within that echo, how do i do it? i tried this;
      `echo '<div><a href = "uploads/$image"</div>'`. 
but doesn't display. Any idea how it can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are not closing the `<?PHP` tag. do it like

```
 <a href = "<?php echo 'uploads/$image'; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: i'm sorry, made a mistake while typing the question. i've edited it.
i'm actually closing it properly in my code

Comment: @dhani: now close tag is there but there is no variable specified with echo. could you please post the exact code you are using?

Comment: You need to `echo "uploads/$image";`

Comment: @Orangepill i'm echoing in my code. somehow my edits didn't show. But it's visible now.

Comment: @dhani: you are missing a semicolon at end. also check by inspecting the source in browser and check the href value is getting properly echoed.