# linked text instead of web address

Tags: php

I've got some php code that is calling in a website link from my database. The result is the full website link 'www.store.com', but what I'd prefer is to just have some linked text e.g., 'read more' so that the actual web address is not visible. The portion of the code that is specific to the website call is as follows:

```
<?php $v['website'] = str_replace('&','&amp;', $v['website']); ?>

<website><?php echo $v['website']; ?></website>
```

Comment: What's `<website>...</website>`?

Comment: Pro Tip: Search for HTML anchor tags.

Comment: I think you must have forgotten to tag another framework or something, as `<website>` is not a valid tag to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In the case `$['website']` contains the web address...

Then you are looking for soemthing like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $['website']; ?>" >Read more </a>
```

I would also recommend add `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag, so the user wont leave your website and the link will open in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried all of the above, but the link just opens up to 'http://read%20more/' and for some reason is not inserting the web link. The code is from another program, that looks to use some sort of placeholder anchors, hence the <website></website> tags.

Comment: what do you have if you only print $['website']; ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `<website>` tag is.  But for the [anchor tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) this,

```
<a href="<?php echo $v['website']; ?>">Read More</a>
```

will work.

Also see,

[Adding php code to html anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501676/adding-php-code-to-html-anchor-tag)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php $v['website'] = str_replace('&','&amp;', $v['website']); ?>

<website><?php echo '<a href="' . $v['website'] . '">Read More</a>'; ?></website>
```

Comment: try to explain it to the OP and the other users, so we all can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, although the read more appears instead of the website link, unfortunately the same result occurs - the link jumps to 'read%more' and not the actual site.